# Saving ALS latent factors in Spark ML to S3 taking too long

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am using a Python script to compute users and items latent factors using Spark ML's ALS routine as described [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html).

After computing latent factors, I am trying to save those to S3 using the following:

```
model = als.fit(ratings)

# save items latent factors
model.itemFactors.rdd.saveAsTextFile(s3path_items)

# save users latent factors
model.userFactors.rdd.saveAsTextFile(s3path_users)
```

There are around 150 million users. LFA is computed quickly (~15 min) but writing out the latent factors to S3 takes almost 5 hours. So clearly, something is not right. Could you please help identify the problem?

I am using 100 users blocks and 100 items blocks in computing LFA using ALS - in case this info might be relevant.

Using 100 r3.8xlarge machines for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Is this EMR, the official ASF Spark version, or something else?

One issue here is that the S3 clients have tended to buffer everything locally onto disk, then only start the upload afterwards.

If it's ASF code, you could make sure you are using Hadoop 2.7.x, use s3a:// as the output schema, and play with the fast output stream options, which can do incremental writes as things get generated. It's a bit brittle in 2.7, will be way better in 2.7.

If you are on EMR, you are on your own there.

Another possible cause is that S3 throttles clients generating lots of HTTPS requests to a particular shard of S3, which means: specific bits of an S3 bucket, with the first 5-8 characters apparently determining the shard. If you can use very unique names there, then you may get throttled less.